# Amazon OpenSearch Service: Expected total copies Error

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I create a domain and when create Index or Vector in it. It error like that

```
[illegal_argument_exception] Validation Failed: 1: expected total copies needs to be a multiple of total awareness attributes [3];
```

How can I fix it?

```js
import { Client } from "@opensearch-project/opensearch";
import { Document } from "langchain/document";
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "langchain/embeddings/openai";
import { OpenSearchVectorStore } from "langchain/vectorstores/opensearch";

const client = new Client({
  nodes: [process.env.OPENSEARCH_URL ?? "http://127.0.0.1:9200"],
  auth: {
    username: process.env.OPENSEARCH_USERNAME ?? "",
    password: process.env.OPENSEARCH_PASSWORD ?? "",
  },
});

const embedding = new OpenAIEmbeddings();
await OpenSearchVectorStore.fromDocuments(docs, embedding, {
    client,
    indexName: process.env.OPENSEARCH_INDEX, // Will default to `documents`
});
```

Comment: Can you share how you try to create the index and please share the following API call?

`GET _cat/nodeattrs?v`

Comment: @MusabDogan I create it using OpenAI like the above code. It runs in local with docker but when I change to Amazon OpenSearch Service it gives this error

Comment: Thanks for your answer can you also share `GET _cat/nodeattrs?v` 

You can use DevTools in kibana

Comment: It return your request is not allowed